# How to display kernel version when i insert any module in c file only?

Tags: linux, module, kernel, version

I am having question regarding to display kernel version from my C program of kernel module. so after insertion i am able to see my kernel version when i display log messages by dmesg.

So my simple C code is as below and please can any one say me how i able to display kernel version after insertion and also same if i am like to insert "who" in program then.
so here you give me solution how to program or which structure i need to include so as i am able to display hostname and kernel version after insertion of module.

Program:

```
#include<linux/init.h>      //for init modules
#include<linux/module.h>    //for kernel modules
#include<linux/kernel.h>    //for kernel function

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");      //For giving licence to module
MODULE_AUTHOR("RAVI BHUVA");    //For authorization of module

static int __init init_hello(void)  //for initialation of module this function is used
{
  printk(KERN_INFO "Hello Master. \nYou are currently using linux ");
  return(0);
}

static void __exit exit_hello(void) //for exiting from module this function is used
{
  printk(KERN_INFO "Good Bye\n");
}

module_init(init_hello);        //for initialation of module
module_exit(exit_hello);        //for exiting from module
```

Answer (score 3):

you can print the version of linux by using the UTS_RELEASE variable . just print it . and ad header file #include

Answer (score 2):

By macro usage.

```
#include<linux/init.h>      //for init modules
#include<linux/module.h>    //for kernel modules
#include<linux/kernel.h>    //for kernel function
#include<generated/utsrelease.h>//For UTS_RELEASE MACRO

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");      //For giving licence to module
MODULE_AUTHOR("RAVI BHUVA");    //For authorization of module

static int __init init_hello(void)  //for initialation of module this function is used
{
printk(KERN_INFO "Hello Master. \nYou are currently using linux %s\n",UTS_RELEASE);//By using macro here i print version of kernel.
return(0);
}

static void __exit exit_hello(void) //for exiting from module this function is used
{
printk(KERN_INFO "Good Bye\n");
}

module_init(init_hello);        //for initialation of module
module_exit(exit_hello);        //for exiting from module
```

By this way you are able to display kernel version.

Answer (score 0):

The above solution will print the kernel version your module was **Compiled** with. So if you want the module to print the version of the kernel is **running** on this will work:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/utsname.h>

static int __init hello_init(void)
{
        pr_alert("You are currently using Linux %s\n", utsname()->release);
        return 0;
}

static void __exit hello_exit(void)
{
        pr_alert("Bye");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

If you look at the proc file system there is a file at path `/proc/version` which spits out a string `Linux version 3.2.0-56-generic (buildd@batsu) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) ) #86-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 23 17:31:43 UTC 2013` describing the version of the kernel running. On further examining `/proc/version.c` the source code of the kernel which actually implements the version file in the proc fs you will see this piece of code which is responsible for the output string:

```
static int version_proc_show(struct seq_file *m, void *v)
{
        seq_printf(m, linux_proc_banner,
                utsname()->sysname,
                utsname()->release,
                utsname()->version);
        return 0;
}
```